# Hybris prettyURL showing PK instead of the real file name

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

The file-name of any image is appearing like 
`/de-de/medias/sys_master/images/images/h9c/h5f/8796178743326/8796178743326.jpg` in the url.
Instead of `8796178743326.jpg` there should be file-name.jpg
I have already set `media.legacy.prettyURL=true`
8796178743326 is the PK of the image.
Any help!

Comment: is the case for all media URL or specific media? If it's for specific media file then I would suggest to check the media file real name in the backoffice.

Comment: adding the value in realFileName attribute in impex worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the prettyURL, if there is no realfilename value in media instance then URL will end with PK instead real file name.

```
/medias/sys_master/images/images/h9c/h5f/8796178743326/8796178743326.jpg
```

If you really want the file name in the URL then you have to edit respective media from the backoffice/impex and assign value to the `realFileName` attribute.

Have a look into **assembleLegacyURL** method of **LocalMediaWebURLStrategy** class

```
        String realFileName = this.getRealFileNameForMedia(mediaSource);

        if (realFileName == null) {

              basePath = mediaSource.getLocation().substring(0, lastDotIdx);
              lastDotIndexForRealFileName = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(basePath, '/');
              String fileName = basePath.substring(lastDotIndexForRealFileName + 1);

              sb.append(basePath).append("/").append(fileName).append('.').append(fileExtension);


           } else {
              basePath = location.substring(0, lastDotIdx);
              lastDotIndexForRealFileName = realFileName.lastIndexOf(46);
              if (lastDotIndexForRealFileName != -1) {

                 realFileName = realFileName.substring(0, lastDotIndexForRealFileName);
              }
              sb.append(basePath).append("/").append(realFileName).append('.').append(fileExtension);
           }
```